# How much time passes between the end of Wings of Liberty and the beginning of Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

Kerrigan is being carried off the field by Raynor in the last part of WoL and looks feeble compared to the beginning of HotS where she is much healthier and energetic.  How much time passed between these events?

Comment: As soon as you start the campaign this question is answered.

Comment: @Ben - What do you mean "she is already in full form at the start of HoS" **that was a dream that Kerrigan had.**

Comment: I guess I meant more along the lines of "able to walk and fight."


@ahsteele, I guess I didn't read the splash screen, which probably means others will do the same, so why the downvotes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the splash screen it says:

> [image] 
>  It's been three weeks since the invasion of Char...

Answer (score 3):

The very first mission's splash page states something to the effect of,

> "It has been 3 weeks since Raynor used the Xel'Naga device and rescued Kerrigan from Char ... "

I will upload a screenshot of this when I have a chance.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you read the Flashpoint book if you want all of the details.

> From what I got in the book, it's been 3 weeks (including the time they pass in warp space).
>
> Mengsk arrive at Char and tells Valerian to surrender Kerrigan. Valerian says no, so Mengsk and his half of the fleet fires of Valerian's half of the fleet (what is left of it).
>
> After that, they run to Deadman's Port to find shelter and make repairs on the Bucephalus and the Hyperion. Some of Mira's men, with the help of the Bartender, reveal their location to Mengsk, so they have to run.
>
> Valerian suggest that they go to Doctor Narud's secret lab, so they can do some tests on Kerrigan and figure out if she is 100% human or if she has a chance of reverting back. Narud betrays Valerian and releases Hybrids to stop Raynor, Valerian, and Kerrigan. Kerrigan goes berserk when Narud almost runs away with the Xel'Naga artifact, kills one hybrid, a hundred Marines, and Anabelle (the engineer from the Hyperion).
>
> Then Valerian suggests that they go to the Umojan Protectorate to study Kerrigan in one of his labs that no one knows about yet.

Comment: It has only been 3 weeks so its neither a month nor 2 months.

Comment: yeah, read that now, the book wasnt exactly specific time wise and didn't read the splash screen before playing the 1st mission.